# How to get the name of an object property?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing my first python program

I created a class, declared properties

How can I get the name of the property 'x' or 'y' and assign it to the variable 'name_property' to implement the function 'operation'?

You will not be able to search by the value of the property, because x, y can be equal

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y


    def operation(value):

        name_value = '???'

        if name_value == 'x':
            return value + 1

        elif name_value == 'y':
            return value - 1

    operation(MyClass.x)
    operation(MyClass.y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of an object property in Python, you can use the getattr() function. The getattr() function returns the value of a named attribute of an object. So in your case:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y


def operation(value):
    if value == getattr(obj, "x"):
        return value + 1

    elif value == getattr(obj, "y"):
        return value - 1

    else:
        # handle case when value is not found
        return None

# Create an instance of MyClass
obj = MyClass(10, 20)

# Call the operation function, passing in the value to search for
result1 = operation(obj.x)
result2 = operation(obj.y)

print(result1, result2)  # Expected output: 11 19
```

Comment: Thanks!
The task is somewhat different, it was necessary to refer to the property inside the class. But, your answer led me to the solution of my problem 